# Magento2 Hide/show custom category attribute based on category level in admin

Tags: magento2, admin

I've created a couple of custom attributes on categories to make it possible for the administrators to create custom menus depending on current category and that works just fine. The thing is that some of those attributes are only relevant for 2nd level categories and some are only relevant for 3rd level categories (and categories deeper in the category tree if there are any).

It makes it very confusing for the administrators if those attributes can be set where they have no effect. So my question is how can I control on which level those attribute inputs will be shown?

None of the attributes are relevant for the RootCategory(1st level) so all inputs should be hidden there.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this link should help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202878/magento-2-1-9-disable-category-attribute-on-condition If you need further clarification, just let me know